# Why is $\textbf{D}$ the response to $\textbf{E}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, condensed-matter, dielectric, optical-materials

In the text [Wooten](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~tanner/Wooten-OpticalPropertiesOfSolids-2up.pdf), equation 2.69 shows $\textbf{D}$ being the response to $\textbf{E}$ with $\epsilon$ as the response function:

$$
\textbf{D}(\textbf{r},t) = \int d\textbf{r}^{\prime} \int dt^{\prime} \epsilon(t,t^{\prime},\textbf{r},\textbf{r}^{\prime}) \textbf{E}(\textbf{r}^{\prime},t^{\prime})
$$

But he also makes the point that (Table 2.1) **D** is the externally applied field, and **E** is the total response from the externally applied field and induced polarization.

It seems to me like **D** and **E** should be switched in that integral, since it makes the total field a response to the applied field.

Am I missing some detail? Can the integral be written in the other way, with, for example with $\textbf{D}$ in the integrand and $\epsilon^{-1}$ as the response function?

Edit: I thought **D** = **E** + **P** (dropping constants) was only the way we write it because the electric *dipole* represented by **P** is opposite to the induced *field*. But this appears to lead to the integral as shown above since we write **P** ~ **E**, and by defining $\epsilon$ we can write

$$
\textbf{D} = \textbf{E} + \textbf{P} = \epsilon \textbf{E}
$$

. But also from above, it seems like **P** (induced polarization) ~ **D** to first-order. Higher order terms establish **P** in a material is proportional to the total field (**E**) in the material.

Comment: I'm pondering what your deeper question is. Is this the gist: Given a known E field, we can calculate D using the integral.  Now, given some D, can we uniquely determine the E field?

Comment: No, that's not my deeper question (at the moment). My deeper question is, what is the intuition and definitions for 1. what I apply, 2. what is induced, 3. what is the total field that obey's Maxwell's equations (written in terms of E and B, not D, E, B, H), and 4. why does the above integral make sense, and 5. am I interpreting it correctly?

Comment: Also, the deeper question is trying to find a way to think about these fields that is not circular.

Comment: Another deeper question is that if E is the total, and D is some non-total field, how can a non-total field depend on the total field?

Comment: To clarify something: He doesn't say that $\textbf{D}$ is the external field $\textbf{E}^{\text{ext}}$, he says that the total field is the sum of $\textbf{E}^{\text{ext}}$ and $\textbf{E}^{\text{ind}}$, where the first comes from $\textbf{D}$ and the second from $\textbf{P}$.

Comment: @PricklebushTickletush, I know you're right...I can't find anywhere where he calls it the external field...but isn't the name implying that it's an external field?

Comment: @von_sohn Sorry about the earlier comment. If I had to take a stab in the dark at guessing the answers to some of your deeper questions, I would say: 1. You apply $\bf{E}$. 2. You induce $\bf{P}$. 3. I think you first have to solve for $\bf{D}$ and then later find $\bf{E}$, but I'm not sure. Not sure how to interpret that integral.

Answer (score 1):

The integral reads: the $D$-field is the retarded and delocalised field as due to the application of the $E$-field on a material which is defined via the $ϵ$ Kernel. It's a standard problem of response theory. The link between $D$ and $E$ is called the constitutive relation, and you need an explicit expression for ϵ to break the self-consistency of the Maxwell equations in materials. This could be done either by measurement and tabulations, or by a microscopic calculation using condensed matter theory. The second third of the 20-th century has been dedicated to this problem, when people tried to calculate $\epsilon$ from quantum mechanics, with more or less success.

The generic form of the constitutive relations can be guessed from symmetry requirements. Note a complete version would also relate the D-field to the B-field (the one without monopole, verifying $\nabla\cdot B =0$), since nothing forbids this in principle (but some symmetries do). Perhaps a reading of [this paragraph of the wikipedia encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#.22Microscopic.22_versus_.22macroscopic.22) might be helpful. All the definitions I'm using follow this page.

To now answer directly your question: you might want to invert the $E-D$ relation, and in general you can, but it's not really helpful because what you usually measure is the $D$ and $H$ fields. In fact, what you really measure are voltage drops and currents in materials, and those are related to $D$ and $H$, not $B$ and $E$. The way to see this is to simply starts from the conservation of current

$$\partial\rho+\nabla\cdot j=0$$

with $\partial\rho\equiv\partial\rho/\partial t$. You can apply the gauge-transform

$$j=j^{\prime}+\nabla\times H-\partial D \;;\; \rho=\rho^{\prime}+\nabla\cdot D$$

you will not alter the conservation of the current. Note that the gauge-transformation above is nothing but the usual Maxwell's equations as defined on [the Wikipedia page cited above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#.22Microscopic.22_versus_.22macroscopic.22), so when you measure charges, you measure the $D-H$-fields. More precisely, you measure their integrals along path, loop, and volume.

In modern experiments using SQUID, you can measure the flux $\int B\cdot dS$ as well, but that's an other story.